# how to take input from keyboard in java till some words

Tags: java, input, keyboard

I want to take input from keyboard in my java program until the user type abc

Here is the code which i have written but it doesn't work. the program continues to take input from keyboard even after i have typed abc and lastly I have to close the program by myself. It takes in input from keyboard and write it on a file named file1.txt

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class io {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file1.txt", true));
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            do {
                writer.write(keyboard.next());
                writer.newLine();
            } while (keyboard.next() != "abc");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two problems - one is calling `keyboard.next()` twice (instead of reading once, and then using the value twice), and the other is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JonSkeet said - you're calling `keyboard.next()` twice instead of storing the result in a local variable like you should. Secondly you're comparing strings with the `!=` operator, but this only checks whether you are pointing to the exact same `String` object. There may be thousands of String objects in memory with the string "abc" in them, and none of them would be equal to each other using `==`.
Instead, you need to call the method `equals`.

```
try {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file1.txt", true));
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String next;
    do {
        next = keyboard.next();
        writer.write(next);
        writer.newLine();
    } while (!next.equals("abc"));
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate...i just forgot about the equals method and stupidly using != operator...well thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

Try this , it works, Just use while loop instead of do while

Code:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class io{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file2.txt", true));
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(!keyboard.next().equals("abc"))
    {
            writer.write(keyboard.next());
            writer.newLine();
    }
         writer.close();
      } 
 catch (IOException e) 
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file1.txt", true));
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  writer.keyboard.nextLine(); // if need write 1st string alltime

  while (keyboard.hasNext()){
  String buffer = keyboard.nextLine();
  if (!"abc".equals(buffer)) //  !!! using equals on object not null ("abc" - is not null)
  {  
       // do if entered "abc", use break for ending while
  }
      // do if entered others, use variable name buffer
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```